# How to write Python code for file upload using REST?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, curl, multipartform-data

I have the below curl command, and I need to write a method for this.
CURL command:

```
curl -X POST "https://example.com:8443/api/rest/abc_service/123/upload/passwd" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "body=@abhifile.txt;type=text/plain"
```

I have written the below method for the same but it fails.
Code:

```
def upload_passwd(self):
    files = {'filename': '/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt'}
    header = {
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    }
    self._request.headers.update(header)
    response = self._request.post(operation='upload/passwd', 
    object_id=self.object_id, files=files)
```

The REST response that I get with above code is:

> The provided class ABC doesn\'t have a JsonObject Constructor or a @ConstructorProperties-annotated constructor that could deserialize the JSON object

I also tried with file open operation with the below code change:

```
def upload_passwd(self):
        f = open('/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt', 'rb')

        header = {
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
        }
        self._request.headers.update(header)
        response = self._request.post(operation='upload/passwd', object_id=self.object_id,
                                      data=f)
```

In the above case, I get error opening the file:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string with the key `filename` instead pass the contents of the file.

```py
def upload_passwd(self):
    files = {'filename': open('/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt','rb')}
    header = {
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    }
    self._request.headers.update(header)
    response = self._request.post(operation='upload/passwd', 
    object_id=self.object_id, files=files)
```

Comment: Hi Shuvojit, I tried with the code you shared, but I am getting this error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: My bad, that returns a context manager, try open('/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt','rb').read()

Comment: I tried by adding .read() as well and the response that I got was "The provided class <xyz> doesn\'t have a JsonObject Constructor or a @ConstructorProperties-annotated constructor that could deserialize the JSON object "

Comment: No no, don't replace the dict with just a string, try this:  {'filename': open('/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt','rb').read()}

Comment: The key 'filename' should point to whatever is returned when you `open()` and `read()` the file.

Comment: Yes. I did the same.My code: files = {'filename': open('/root/Desktop/vdm/abhifile.txt', 'rb').read()} and it threw the error mentioned in above comment.